# C# Outlook.MailItem sender name encoding

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm making outlook vsto plugin for sending email, and I have a problem with encoding.
If I send only english characters in message it is encoded as ascii, and in outlook sender name doesn't display serbian latin characters.
If I send serbian latin characters in message it is encoded as iso-8859-2, and in outlook sender name is fine.

```
Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = _app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

mail.To = txtTo.Text;
mail.Subject = "Promena adrese";

mail.Body = txtPackageNum.Text + " " + txtNewAddress.Text;

mail.Send();
```

[Here's what it looks like in inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imyem.jpg)

How can I fix this? I would like encoding to be utf-8 no matter what is sent in message

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you send the same message manually through Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

please try below code,

```
mail.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

This will encode your message in utf8 format. if you also want to encode subject then you can use

```
mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

For more information you can also visit msdn page 
[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately Outlook.MailItem does not contain .BodyEncoding or .SubjectEncoding

Comment: try mail.InternetCodepage = 65001;
URL : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-internetcodepage-property-outlook